# Simple parallel process in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a (very) simple process to carry out many times, along the lines of:

```
import time

class Shop:
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(1.)
        self.sale_price = 0
    def update(self, weight, price):
        self.sale_price = weight * price
        
my_list = [Shop() for _ in range(20)]  #20 shops

weight, price = 2, 3

for o in my_list:
    o.update(weight, price)
```

(The function `update` changes the internal state of `o`, without any return value)

**my question: What's a simple way to make this loop/process run in parallel?**

I've seen many examples here for parallel mathematical operations (e.g. matrix operations), but I can't get them working for my simple example. I'm using Python 3.6.5

Comment: Where did you define `my_list`?

Comment: I've added a full example below, showing ```my_list``` definition.

Comment: I don't see you trying to parallelize anything anywhere. What did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: Current example is not parallelised - I want to know how to replace the for-loop and make it work in parallel. I've tried a few things, including the examples on https://stackabuse.com/parallel-processing-in-python/

Comment: What happened when you tried the code in the linked post?

Comment: Their example seems to run alright if I execute the file via CLI (making use of ```if __name__ == '__main__'```), but I don't seem to be able to just run it like the for-loop in my example. (i.e. so I can call it line-by-line in an IDE like Spyder, without a ```__main__```). Having to use ```__main__``` would be an issue for the project I'm using this in, so I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Comment: @Mich55 You don't have to use  `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Remove it and shift left the rest of code. Results will be the same

Comment: @Mich55 you have to use a `__main__` guard to use multiprocessing. There's no reason it should stop you from using it in whatever project. You **need to provide an example and a description of exactly what isn't working for you**. Otherwise the answer to your question is basically exactly what is in that link.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. However, I wasn't trying to replicate the linked example per se. I was asking if there is any simple, short solution that doesn't require much additional code (like the one eventually found, posted below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution:

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

class Shop:
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(1.)
        self.sale_price = 0
    def update(self, weight, price):
        self.sale_price = weight * price
        
my_list = [Shop() for _ in range(20)]  #20 shops
weight, price = 2, 3



### Non-parallel
for o in my_list:
    o.update(weight, price)



### Parallel
#Helper function (doesn't take weight/price parameters - assumes these are already defined)
def update2(o):
    o.update(weight, price)
    return o
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
my_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(update2)(o) for o in my_list)
```

I realise this reassigns `my_list` at the end, but this is fine for my purpose.